# Deleting a name from list of names in HTML table with button click on corresponding row

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database, forms

I use Rails,

I have a HTML table like

Name Age

ABCD   10

EFGH    20

Now these rows are fetched from database, I need to add a delete button to each row and then delete the row from database on a click to it. I know I can add many Submit buttons with same name and different values corresponding to 'id' of each row and identify the button clicked. But I don't want to reveal the 'id' of each row to the user.

So is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You don't want to reveal the column id in the client code?

Comment: Nope I dont want to reveal the 'id' of corresponding row in database to user so I cannot use that as value of Submit button

Comment: You could setup an MD5 on the id field, or you could setup another unique identifier column to represent the user

Answer (score 1):

The delete link needs some way to identify which record to delete, right?  Consider using something like https://github.com/norman/friendly_id to generate permalinks for your records, and then identify the record using those permalinks, instead of DB primary keys.